# Error happens when trying to umount the Lustre file system

Tags: unix, umount, lustre

When I umount Lustre FS it displays:

```
[root@cn17663-ens4 mnt]# umount /mnt/lustre 
umount: /mnt/lustre: target is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

and if I add the force option `-f` it gives the same result:

```
[root@cn17663-ens4 mnt]# umount /mnt/lustre -f
umount: /mnt/lustre: target is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

When I try to list the directory it gives me :

```
[root@cn17663-ens4 mnt]# ls
ls: cannot access lustre: Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown
lustre
```

and I cannot find what the reason is and cannot solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually try running `lsof /mnt/lustre` (as the error message recommends) to see what is using the filesystem?  This problem is not unique to Lustre, but true of any local filesystem as well - if there is a process using the filesystem (current working directory or open file) then it can't be unmounted until that process stops using it (`cd` out of `/mnt/lustre` or close the open file(s)).

Comment: Right @LustreOne the described behavior might caused by a stale mount.

Answer (score 0):

I find I can use `umount -l /mnt/xx` to solve this problem!